# How can I refresh RecyclerView in a fragment after database changes in Android Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

RecyclerView not refreshing on Fragment after database change

I'm building an app that registers events of the charger being connected and disconnected. For now I've only implemented the "connected" status, since the other part is basically the same principle.

Please note that i'm new in Android development so the way i've implemented things may look dumb

So...

A broadcast receiver listens for an Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED and starts an IntentService.

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent

class BatteryChangedReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        if (intent.action == Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED) {
            context.startService(Intent(context, BatteryChangedService::class.java))
        }
    }
}
```

The IntentService do a debugInsert() which just puts a random value on the database. The database itself is working properly so I'll ommit db and repository implementations here

```
import android.app.IntentService
import android.content.Intent
import android.widget.Toast
import com.example.nopowerlcc3.database.RegisterRepository
import com.example.nopowerlcc3.database.RegistersAdapter

class BatteryChangedService : IntentService("BatteryChanged") {

    override fun onHandleIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        var repo = RegisterRepository.getInstance(applicationContext)
        val adapter = RegistersAdapter()

        Thread.sleep(5000)

        if (repo.debugInsert()) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Energia voltou", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            adapter.refresh()
        }
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "service started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Service stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        super.onDestroy()
    }

}
```

**The problem is, when the data is inserted my Home Fragment doesn't update itself, making me have to reload it by changing fragments or reopening the application**

My adapter:

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.nopowerlcc3.databinding.RowRegisterBinding

class RegistersAdapter() : RecyclerView.Adapter<RegisterViewHolder>() {
    var registerList: ArrayList<Register> = ArrayList()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RegisterViewHolder {
        val item = RowRegisterBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)

        return RegisterViewHolder(item)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RegisterViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(registerList[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return registerList.count()
    }

    fun updateRegisters(list: ArrayList<Register>) {
        registerList.clear()
        registerList.addAll(list)
        refresh()
    }

    fun refresh() {
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

The fragment in question:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.nopowerlcc3.database.RegistersAdapter
import com.example.nopowerlcc3.databinding.FragmentHomeBinding

class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    private lateinit var adapter: RegistersAdapter
    private lateinit var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        adapter = RegistersAdapter()

        homeViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
        homeViewModel.getAll()

        // Layout
        binding.recyclerRegisters.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        // Adapter
        binding.recyclerRegisters.adapter = adapter


        observe()

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

    private fun observe() {
        homeViewModel.registers.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            adapter.updateRegisters(it)
        }
    }


}
```

**Edit:** the ViewModel:

```
import android.app.Application
import androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import com.example.nopowerlcc3.database.Register
import com.example.nopowerlcc3.database.RegisterRepository

class HomeViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val repo = RegisterRepository.getInstance(application.applicationContext)

    private val registersList = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Register>>()
    val registers: LiveData<ArrayList<Register>> = registersList

    fun getAll() {
        registersList.value = repo.getAll()
    }

    fun debugInsert() {
        repo.debugInsert()
    }
}
```